# Guardar opcion seleccionada en angular?

Tags: angular

Tengo el siguiente codigo y quiero saber como guardar nombre de campo seleccionada.

```
<mat-tab label="Unique">          
            <mat-form-field *ngIf="!detector ; else alert" class="m-5" style="width: 400px">
                <mat-label>Seleccione las Unique</mat-label>                
                <mat-select multiple ">
                  <ng-container *ngFor="let campo of campos">
                    <mat-option 
                    *ngIf="campo.nombreCampo != null">{{campo.nombreCampo}}
                  </mat-option>
                </ng-container>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field> 
        </mat-tab>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estabas muy cerca, tienes que usar la directiva `(ngModel)` para a poder obtener el valor del `<select>` aunque estas implementando tu `select` y depende si lo quieres hacer multiple `select`:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="opcionSeleccionado" (change)="capturar()">
    <option value="0">Selecciona una opción</option>
    <option *ngFor="let dato of datos">
      {{dato}}
    </option>
</select>
<!-- Prueba para ver la opción seleccionado -->

    <p [hidden]="opcionSeleccionado == '0'">Haz seleccionado la opción # {{ verSeleccion }}</p>

export class AppComponent  {
  datos;
  // Seleccionamos o iniciamos el valor '0' del <select>
  opcionSeleccionado: string  = '0';
  verSeleccion: string        = '';

  constructor(){
      this.datos = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
  }  

  capturar() {
      // Pasamos el valor seleccionado a la variable verSeleccion
      this.verSeleccion = this.opcionSeleccionado;
  }
}
```

Comment: una pregunta. Al ngModel , automaticamente toma el valor del select? y el evento change estaria guardandole el valor dependiendo de la opcion seleccionada?

Comment: Si guardaría siempre y cuando le asignes un valor al ngModel

Comment: y el valor que le asigno el ngModel de donde tendria que venir? del for? o cuando yo seleccione una opcion . automaticamente el ngModel sabe su valor? ( en este caso seria el nombreDelCampo seleccionada)